# Plot a map with arrows for commuters

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas

I'm trying to plot a map, where arrows indicate information. In my specific case I have several data from commuters, from town A to town B, from town C to town B and so on. I'm missong some keywords on how to find information about that, how to plot such a map, that

1. The commuters path is not only a line, but maybe an arrow and also not totally straight
2. The thickness of the line indicates the amount of commuters

I'm normally working with QGIS and geopandas and I'm quite sure, that my idea is no rocket science, so probably there is already some plugin/tool/module out there, to create such a map.

Can anybody help me with some keywords on how to find more information about this?

Comment: Sometghing like this ? https://anitagraser.com/2016/12/30/new-style-flow-map-arrows/ ;

Comment: https://anitagraser.com/2016/12/30/new-style-flow-map-arrows/ - this is how such a map can/should look like - but the workflow is way easier nowadays, you can style everything using the GUI and data defined override.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks for the link. Some good hints over there :) Any possibility to make something like this with geopandas too?